# server error in web api 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: asp.net

Sir I have developed an asp .net web api using mvc 4. I have deployed it on local iis in local machine as well server. I am getting response both on same machine .
      But when I try to access using domain name from same machine as well as from another machine i am getting following error .
     Also I am trying to access from windows server using Ip it is giving me same error......

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the host in your hosts-file?

```
Example for Windows 8

Press the Windows key.
Type Notepad in the search field.
In the search results, right-click Notepad and select Run as administrator.
In Notepad, open the following file: c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
Make the necessary changes to the file.
Click File > Save to save your changes.
```

If you want www.my-domain.com to match 192.168.1.55 then add

192.168.1.55 www.my-domain.com

to your hosts file.